# Todo task list in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am building a Todo app in javascript, and I am facing 3 issue:
1. Setting the checked attribute on input element upon ticking the list. 
`<input type="checkbox" value="Go to Gym">`
Is this statement wrong?

```
checkbox.checked = data.status;
```

2) Storing the data using session.

`if(sessionStorage['task'] != null)`

3) The status of the items(i.e checked or unchecked) are failing to update in dataJSON object in UpdateJSON function.

```
function updateJSON(event) {
    let key = event.target.value;
    dataJSON[key].status = event.target.checked;
    sessionStorage['task'] = JSON.stringify(dataJSON);
}
```

```js
var output = document.querySelector('#output'),
    taskList = document.querySelector('#taskList'),
    html = '',
    dataJSON='';
    document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userInput = document.querySelector('input[name="task"]'),
        tempValue = userInput.value;
        console.log(tempValue);
        userInput.value = '';
        console.log(dataJSON);
        addNewElement({"info": tempValue,"status": false})
    });

    //console.log(data);
    window.onload = function(){
        if(sessionStorage['taskList'] != null){
            dataJSON = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['task']);
        } else {
            var data = '[{"info":"Cut Grass","status":true},{"info":"Clear Roo","status":false},{"info":"Go to Gym","status":true},{"info":"Make dinner","status":false}]';
            dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        }
        buildCheckboxesData(dataJSON);
    };

    function addNewElement(data) {
        addCheckbox(data, data.length);
        dataJSON.push(data);
    }
    function addCheckbox(data, key) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(data.info);
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.value = data.info;
        checkbox.checked = data.status;
        checkbox.onchange = updateJSON;
        li.appendChild(textNode);
        li.appendChild(checkbox);
        taskList.appendChild(li);
    }

    function buildCheckboxesData(data){
        for(let key in data){
            addCheckbox(data[key], key)
         }
    }


    function updateJSON(event) {
        let key = event.target.value;
        dataJSON[key].status = event.target.checked;
        sessionStorage['taskList'] = JSON.stringify(dataJSON);
    }
```

```html
<div id="output">
    <ul id="taskList"></ul>
</div>
<form id="myForm" action="">
    Task: <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="add task">
    <button type="submit">Add new Task</button>
</form>
```

Comment: " facing issue"...so...what's the issue then? Must we guess? please clarify what precisely is your problem, and where you think it occurs. You have given us quite a lot of code to work with, and almost no worthwhile explanation.

Comment: I have rephrased the issues, hope this is helpful. @ADyson

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hrzyv256/3/ there's nothing wrong with `checkbox.checked = data.status;` assuming that `status` is actually always a boolean. However `dataJSON[key].status` in your updateJSON method makes no sense and it causes a console error...`key` is something like "Cut Grass", but `dataJSON` is an array and they don't have named keys, only numeric indexes like `0`. You'd be better to make the value of the checkbox the index of the item in the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question, why isn't the session not storing the state of the app? I am missing out something over there?

Comment: Hey! I think I gave a wrong reference of the form element to the sessiion. I got it. Thank you so much! That was a great help.

Comment: BTW you know that sessionStorage is temporary? It will expire when the browser is closed or whatever. Not much help for a to-do list which lasts more than a day. I don't know your requirements really but maybe you should consider localStorage. Or of course if the user may want to access the list from another device then you'll need a server-based solution, but that's another story.